# Couple of questions on mysql table creation

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE favorite_food(
    person_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    food VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT pk_favorite_food PRIMARY KEY(person_id,food),
    CONSTRAINT fk_fav_food_person_id FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
    REFERENCES person (person_id)
);
```

I am new to MySQL and coming purely from **HTML and JS background**. I have couple of questions here.

1. Why do we need to give a CONSTRAINT a name like "`pk_favorite_food`". What is the purpose and use behind it?
2. What does the REFERENCES mean?
3. `CONSTRAINT pk_favorite_food PRIMARY KEY(person_id,food),` Why do we add two columns as Primary Key here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### First

> Why do we need to give a CONSTRAINT a name like "pk_favorite_food". What is the purpose and use behind it?

You are not *required* to assign a name to the constraint, and if you do not, MySQL will assign one internally for you. It is merely an identifier, which makes it easier to modify or drop the constraint later.

If you create the table without that constraint name and then do `SHOW CREATE TABLE favodite_food;`, you will see a name somewhat similar to the one you have defined above, but assigned automatically by MySQL. The automatically created identifiers would likely be something like `idx_favorite_food` for the primary key and `favorite_food_ibfk_1` for the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.

#### Second

> What does the `REFERENCES` mean?

`REFERENCES` is a keyword used in `FOREIGN KEY` constraints to indicate which table the `FOREIGN KEY` column refers to a column in. Read [the MySQL reference on `FOREIGN KEY` constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) for full syntactic details.  In your example, it looks a little strange because it appears on its own line. Really, it belongs to the `FOREIGN KEY` definition.

It may be a little clearer if you see it on the line it belongs to:

```
/* REFERENCES is a component of this FOREIGN KEY definition */
CONSTRAINT fk_fav_food_person_id FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person (person_id)
```

#### Third

> `CONSTRAINT pk_favorite_food PRIMARY KEY(person_id,food)`, Why do we add two columns as Primary Key here.

The 2 part `PRIMARY KEY` is called a *composite key*. It is used when you don't need a single identifying column (like an auto-increment value), but the combination of those two columns must be unique in the table and can therefore also uniquely identify the row in the table.  So in the example you have above, it enforces the fact that any `person_id` cannot have two rows with the same `food`:

```
INSERT INTO favorite_food (person_id, food) VALUES (1, 'apples'); /* works */
INSERT INTO favorite_food (person_id, food) VALUES (1, 'bananas'); /* works */
INSERT INTO favorite_food (person_id, food) VALUES (1, 'apples'); /* Fails!  Person 1 already has apples and the pair must be unique */
```

Answer (score 1):

I reply to you one by one:

> **Q** Why do we need to give a CONSTRAINT a name like "`pk_favorite_food`". What is the purpose and use behind it?

**A** In relational model you should be able to differentiate one row of all other. For this reason you should choose several fields that its value is unique for each row. For a comtination of value of this field you have the certainty that only a row will catch with this values.

> **Q** What does the REFERENCES mean?

**A** This means that a value stored in this fields is a kind of pointer to a other table row.

> **Q** `CONSTRAINT pk_favorite_food PRIMARY KEY(person_id,food),` Why do we add two columns as Primary Key here.

**A** Because in this case is not enough with one field. If you include only person that means that a person only can take a favorite food and if you take only food that means that a food can be favorite for more than one person.

Notice: this is a basic explanation, you should learn about relational model an integrity reference.

Answer (score 1):

We need to give the CONSTRAINT a name because your database will store it somewhere, and that name is how you will get to it.  For example running:

```
select *
from information_schema.table_constraints
where constraint_schema = 'YOUR_DB_NAME'
```

Will show you the list of constraints.  It makes sense for each of them to have a name so you can identify them.

The references keyword is used to define which table and column is used in a foreign key relationship. In this case, your person_id from favourite food references the person_id in the person table.

With regards to the primary keys - The number you use is up to you as the developer.

I would recommend you spend some time reading through the documentation such as the guide here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

1. The name shows you the function of the CONSTRAINT, so it is easier to find out what it is doing later (pk for example says it is a PRIMARY KEY, fk is a FOREIGN KEY)
2. REFERENCES means the referenced table for the FOREIGN KEY. That means that the 'person_id' in the table 'favorite_food' is refrenced to the 'person_id' in the person table. That has the effect, that if you push data into favorite_food table the 'person_id' you enter has to exist in the 'person' table, otherwise you get an error, so you can't add a favorite food to a non existent person.
3. This CONSTRAINT means, that the PRIMARY KEY for each entry in this table is combined of the columns 'person_id' and 'food', so you always have a unique combination of person and food, so that one person can only have one favorite food