# mysql 1064 error on execution

Tags: mysql-error-1064

***I´ve got this table:***

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE favorite food
-> (person_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
->food VARCHAR(20),
->CONSTRAINT pk_favorite_food PRIMARY KEY (person_id, food),
->CONSTRAINT fk_fav_food_person_id FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
->REFERENCES person (person_id)
->);
```

***After execution i get the error 1064. Anybod any ideas what could be wrong?***

MySQL Server 6.0

Comment: Check this question, it might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706498/mysql-error-1064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By searching some possible response on Google, I found [this thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606183/couple-of-questions-on-mysql-table-creation)... The original table (which is the same as your, but with a nicer formatting) is:

```
CREATE TABLE favorite_food(
    person_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    food VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT pk_favorite_food PRIMARY KEY(person_id,food),
    CONSTRAINT fk_fav_food_person_id FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(person_id)
);
```

1. You probably don't have the `person` table, so the foreign key can't be created. (see the last line)
2. You have remove the `_` in the table name (`favorite food` instead of `favorite_food`) which is not allowed.

Comment: I already have the "person" table created, so the problem could be the "white space" in the table name.

Answer (score 3):

Table name should not have a whitespace in it.  Make it something like `favorite_food`